# List authors with paging and avatar sorted by nicename in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

As the title says I am looking for a way to display authors in a way so I can use pagination for the results and split them over several pages. Much like a normal post query where I can use `posts_per_page=5&paged=$paged`

Comment: Hi Thomas, did you ever figure this out? This is exactly what I need.

Answer (score 0):

There is this function in WP: wp_list_authors([options])

http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_authors

It functions similar to query_posts(), but not exactly. Check out this other page on the Codex for examples and tutorials:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Author_Templates

Comment: Thanks I know wp_list_authors. It does not do pagging or avatar by deafult, so not really an option. I guess my question is how do I do paging on a query that returns authors and not posts or pages

Comment: Ah, I see. I guess you'd need custom queries to get what you want. Give me some time and I can probably write something similar to what you want. (After work).